# How to conform NSView to CALayerDelegate when you import SwiftUI?

Tags: calayer, swiftui, nsview, appkit

This compiles:

```
import AppKit

class CustomView: NSView, CALayerDelegate {
    func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {}
}
```

This does not however:

```
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

class CustomView: NSView, CALayerDelegate {
    func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {}
}
```

This is an error:

```
... error: redundant conformance of 'CustomView' to protocol 'CALayerDelegate'
class CustomView: NSView, CALayerDelegate {}
                          ^
... note: 'CustomView' inherits conformance to protocol 'CALayerDelegate' from superclass here
class CustomView: NSView, CALayerDelegate {}
      ^
```

Any idea how to fix this?

*If you remove `CALayerDelegate` conformance, delegate methods are not called.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They’re not called because the compiler can’t see they’re implementing the protocol and thus won’t make them available from Objective-C. But you can still make it available manually with the `@objc` attribute. You should also specify the Objective-C selector name, which isn’t always the same name as in Swift:

```
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

class CustomView: NSView {
    @objc(layoutSublayersOfLayer:)
    func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Michel didn't work for me because I had a different method that was causing the problem.

```
@objc(drawLayer:inContext:)
func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext)
{}
```

The general solution is still to check the `Objective-C` method which is implemented in your custom `Swift` file and use the: 
`@objc(methodName)` above the `Swift` method name.

Here is a list of CALayerDelegate's methods (5):

Swift -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayerdelegate

Objective-C -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayerdelegate?language=objc